# Magnetic levitation against Earnshaw's Theorem?

Tags: magnetic-fields, statics, magnetostatics, ferromagnetism, levitation

Given six strong magnets, what if we fix three of them to a table in a simple, horizontal, equilateral triangle-like formation (with their north poles sticking up), and the other three to the points of a rigid wooden (same size) equilateral triangle, with their north poles facing down? We can overlay these two triangles in a perfect "Star of David" formation, and statically levitate the latter triangle above the table by the repulsion of the fields. No moving charges or fields required, just some wood and six strong permanent magnets. The weight of the triangle & magnets will prevent "flipping", while the repulsive magnetic fields will prevent "spinning" or lateral movement as well.

Does this violate Earnshaw's theorem somewhere?

Comment: what if one magnet was microscopicaly out of position? Would this take energy to move to a stable configuration?

Comment: You cannot violate Earnshaw's theorem with static magnets.  For the possible loopholes, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earnshaw%27s_theorem#Loopholes

Comment: @MartinBeckett Seems pretty stable to me. Was there a direction of perturbation you had in mind? I addressed how lateral movement, rotation, and flipping would be discouraged.

Comment: @PeterDiehr Doesn't my setup violate it? The wikipedia article mentions loopholes via walls or tethers, but is there really something that counts as a wall or tether somewhere in my setup?

Comment: @ManRow: Sorry, but your device is unstable without a tether.  You can test this by touching it lightly, from any direction.  Try the experiment: build it, and video the results!

Comment: @PeterDiehr Hmm i was thinking there should be some mathematically obvious place or way where the magnetic fields cancel out and allow the top part to move without restriction. But I can't seem to figure it out from the top of my head -- I am looking for a mathematical reason or explanation as to why my setup does not indicate some kind of potential energy "well" (of gravitational and magnetic potential energies) in the statically levitated position. More of a thought experiment too then, really! I do suppose my magnetically levitated triangle might not count for the "wall/tether" loophole tho

Comment: Or, perhaps Earnshaw's theorem is limited to one "kind" of inverse-square force *at a time* -- i.e., it works when considering "only" magnetic forces or "only" gravitational ones, but says nothing regarding *combinations* of multiple different kinds of forces at the same time that can act "independently" of one another (e.g., magnetic fields are not affected by gravity, etc...). So, my example is likely a stable static levitation that doesn't actually violate Earnshaw's theorem because there is an implicit "wall/tether" created by the invisible, non-magnetism-interfering force of gravity.

Comment: @ManRow: just look at the link provided earlier for the conditions.  The mathematical proof is in Earnshaw's theorem.  If you study the proof carefully, you should be able to see that any such configuration is unstable.  The proof is generally done as homework in a junior/senior level field theory class.

Comment: @PeterDiehr Will take a closer look. So far just only skimping through it doesn't look like the Wikipedia proof showed a combination of magnetic and gravitational fields, nor even brought up gravity at all even in the simplified linear sense F = m * g. In my case the stationary table magnets are trying to stretch out the levitated triangle platform's magnets (which stay put due to being affixed to the vertices of the levitated platform)

Comment: So how's that video coming along? ;)

Comment: Here's an empirical reason why this violates Earnshaw's theorem: can you buy one?  Because such a thing would be a seriously cool toy, at least.

Comment: Not really -- sometimes cool toys have to be DIY'ed : P But funny use of "empiricism" there -- that's like saying "everyone in this community believes in Christianity so it must be true" lol

Comment: Except I have such a thing, which relies on electronics to work (ie there are servoed electromagnets involved), and I have seen others which don't but which have a support.  I was using 'empirical' in the sense of 'observational' or 'experimental'.

Comment: Doesn't logically imply electronics or electromagnets are "required" ; ) My support is just the downward force of gravity

Comment: Indeed not: Earnshaw's theorem says they are required (or at least diamagnetic materials).  My 'empirical' comment was merely meant to back the theorem up: not only do we theoretically know such things don't work, we don't observe them in practice.  I'm not going to respond further as this is not going anywhere.

Comment: So then, where in my setup are the mathematical saddle paths/directions? They have to exist, after all, for my levitation to be "unstable"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, essentially my idea was to create a setup where the individual "saddle paths" of the levitated platform's magnets and/or charges are oriented in such a way that one part of the levitated platform moving towards lower potential would require the rest to move into higher potential (referring to the total sum of gravity & electrostatic potential energies), in such a way so as to create an (gravity + electrostatic) potential energy well for the "overall structure" as a whole at the levitation position.

While there can be numerous different arrangements of opposing individual saddle paths  for individual charges or magnets fixed to a levitating platform above some collection of charges or magnets fixed to the ground, there doesn't seem to be an obvious arrangement of everything that would *necessarily* lead to a (gravitational + electrostatic + ferromagnetic) potential energy well for the levitated structure as a whole.

I have not fully analyzed all the full equipotential surface(s) of my setup specifically, but looking at some simpler similar examples it doesn't look like these kind of potential energy wells can exist, even if the specific saddle path(s) of my full setup can be difficult or nontrivial to find or visualize (comprising some specific complicated or unforseen combination of rolling, spinning, spiraling, etc... movement(s))

Answer (score -2):

Earnshaw's theorem only applies to electrostatic systems, which consist of static point charges. It does not have anything to say either way about the stability of your system, since that is a system composed of magnetic components.

The origin of Earnshaw's theorem can be traced to Gauss' law, which essentially states that the electric potential $\phi$ obeys Poisson's equation
$$-\nabla^2 \phi = \rho$$
where $\rho$ is the charge density. You may recall from an analysis class that solutions to Laplace's equation have the property that over some region of space $R$ they have no local extrema (unless they are constant). Thus, there is no point where the electric force (the derivative of $\phi$) vanishes and is attractive in all directions.

If the system is not static or involves magnetic fields, then the electric potential $\phi$ is not a complete description of the dynamics and Earnshaw's theorem won't apply. Additionally, since magnetic forces don't originate from a Gauss' law-like form (recall there are no magnetic charges), Earnshaw's theorem can't be applied.

Comment: There is more than one version of Earnshaw's theorem. There are versions that deal with magnetism, as described in the WP article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earnshaw's_theorem

Comment: Earnshaw's theorem does apply to magnets whose field does not depend on applied fields I think.

Comment: Interesting, my mistake. In this case, judging from the "loopholes" section of the linked Wikipedia page, it seems like constrained motion may provide another way to circumvent the instability.

Comment: Yup, essentially the idea is to create a setup where the individual "saddle paths" of the levitated magnets and/or charges are oriented in such a way that one part of the levitated platform moving towards lower potential would require the rest to move into higher potential (referring to the total sum of gravity & electrostatic potential energies), in such a way to create an overall (gravity + electrostatic) potential energy well for the "overall structure" at the levitation position.